# issue lapply multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am trying to apply a function to a list of data frames. The data frames are three lists of georeferenced points. I want to add one column to every data frame with information about the cell id of the cell where each point falls in.

Here is the function :

```
vectorData<-list(df1,df2,df3)
lapply(vectorData,function(x){x<-spatialEco::point.in.poly(x,grid)})
```

It gives me the appropriate result however I want to store this result in a new column in each data frame.

If I do it for each data frame with the following code it works fine:

```
df1<-spatialEco::point.in.poly(ds1,grid)
```

Comment: @IanCampbell, thank you for this comment. I did add `x$new` to the code but the result remains the same. After running the code I see the result printed in the console but it does not merge with the rest of the dataframes.

Comment: @IanCampbell, thank you again. With a `for` is this structure correct? `vectorData<-list(df1, df2, df3) for (V in vectorData){V<-spatialEco::point.in.poly(V,grid)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`point.in.poly`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatialEco/versions/1.3-2/topics/point.in.poly), by default, it returns an `sp` object. So you won't be able to assign this to a new column of your data.frames.

One approach would be to pre-initialize the a `result` list and assign the output of `point.in.poly` to elements of the list:

```
result <- list()
for (i in seq_along(vectorData)) {
  result[[i]] <- spatialEco::point.in.poly(vectorData[[i]],grid)
}
```